# Servlet static field exposed through a method -- Need Data Integrity

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a Servlet named `AbcServlet.java`, In this I have a `Static String field called cacheSeller`. It is being populated in the `init` **and** `doGet` method of the servlet. And it is cleared by a `CacheSellerClearThread.java` shown below:

**AbcServlet.java**

```
public class AbcServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static String cacheSeller = null;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        cacheSeller = populateCacheSeller();
    }

    /**
     * As soon as multiple requests are coming doGet is being called
     */
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        synchronized (this.getClass()) {
            if (cacheSeller == null) {
                cacheSeller = populateCacheSeller();
            }
        }

    }

    private String populateCacheSeller() {
        String fetchItFromSomewhere = "";// some logic to fetch the sting
        return fetchItFromSomewhere;
    }

    public static synchronized void clearCacheSeller() {
        cacheSeller = null;
    }
}
```

**CacheSellerClearThread.java**

```
/**
 * This thread is clearing the string field cacheSeller of AbcServlet 
 *
 */
public class CacheSellerClearThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Here it is clearing the static string field cacheSeller of AbcServlet
            AbcServlet.clearCacheSeller();
        }
    }
}
```

if you look at the code, cacheSeller value is being read and modified in the doGet method. All the request threads will execute the doGet, at the same time CacheSellerClearThread will be clearing its value after every 2 sec. So to maintain the data integrity of cacheSeller value, I use synchronization.

I need a suggestion that Is there any other way to achieve this without using explicit synchronization in the clearCacheSeller method and without applying explicit class level locking in the Servlet. (I mean to say using any advanced concurrent APIs like atomic reference or any other you can suggest.)

**I have written the new implementation using AtomicReference, Please suggest, Do I need to use synchronization anywhere.**

```
public class AbcServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static AtomicReference<String> cacheSeller = new AtomicReference<String>();

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        cacheSeller.set(populateCacheSeller());
    }

    /**
     * As soon as multiple requests are coming doGet is being called
     */
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (cacheSeller.get() == null) {
            cacheSeller.compareAndSet(null, populateCacheSeller());
        }
        resp.getWriter().print(cacheSeller.get());
    }

    private String populateCacheSeller() {
        String fetchItFromSomewhere = "";// some logic to fetch the sting
        return fetchItFromSomewhere;
    }

    public static void clearCacheSeller() {
        cacheSeller.set(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: first, It is never been a good idea to have static instance variable in servlet class

Comment: @niiraj874u I agree with you, but this is something i can't change this is as per the design.

Comment: When do you create and start thread to clear it ? I presume that you know that init method will be called only once in its servlet's life

Comment: Yeah I know that init method will be called only once, But cacheSeller value is being read and modified in the doGet method as well. All the request threads will execute the doGet, at the same time CacheSellerClearThread will be clearing its value after every 2 sec.

Comment: @niiraj874u I have changed the last line in the question, I think It will become more clear.

Comment: Why do you call the method populateCacheSeller twice in the init method and in the doGet method?

Comment: @Dimitri we can avoid calling it in the init method. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) framework.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AbcServlet.clearCacheSeller();
            }
        }, 2L,2L,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And in your `doGet`, only synchronize initialization:

```
 @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String localCacheSeller = cacheSeller; 
            if (cacheSeller == null) {
                synchronized (this.getClass()) {
                     if (cacheSeller == null) { //need this because cacheSeller may already have been initialized while we waited
                         cacheSeller = populateCacheSeller();
                         localCacheSeller = cacheSeller; //because the executor may clear it after we initialized
                     }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Basically You have suggested me a way to create a scheduler using Executor Framework. But I require some way to avoid the explicit locking. BTW Thanks for suggesting the double check for null value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to create your cache.

For example:

```
LoadingCache<String, String> cache =
 CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
 .expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
 .build(loader);
```

Having something like this you could avoid your secondary thread to clear the cache.

This implementation is a simple in-memory cache and it is thread-safe as well.

Regards

Comment: Is it possible using the java concurrent API classes to use something else than synchronization? I mean any API that abstract the locking features. Thanks for the solution using Guava API.

Comment: I would suggest AtomicReference

Comment: @Dimitri Don't you think by using AtomicReference also, we require explicit synchronization. Please suggest.

Comment: AtomicReference is a class that encapsulates a reference (or object) and guarantees that all operations (read/updates) within this object are atomic.

Comment: @Dimitri, I like the AtomicReference suggestion. But the thing that concerns me is the need of having an extra thread to cleanup the cache. I think using something like Guava is more clean, flexible and lightweight.

Comment: @Dimitri I agree with you regarding atomicity. But here first we need to check if the variable is null, then we need to populate it. So read and update are two different operations, How AtomicRefernce will maintain these two operation as atomic.

Comment: Yes Pedro, you are totally right. And for now, I dont want to think about it :). Your solution is better. @SAM, there is no need to check if the variable is null. The constructor AtomicReference() already sets the current reference to null. You only have to call compareAndSet every time you have to update the value.

Comment: @Dimitri I have applied the null check because every time I do not want to invoke populateCacheSeller method. In case, the value is null, then only call compareAndSet and populateCacheSeller is invoked. Am I making sense?

Comment: @Dimitri Just one more comment please :)